# How is the power distributed in laptops when simultaneously charging and using?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, laptop

How does my laptop charge as well as discharge at the same time? As far as I know, the battery cannot be charged and discharged at the same time. Please explain how the power is distributed when charging while it is in use.

Comment: Not really an issue. KCL applies and what’s not “stolen” to run the laptop, goes into the battery. Have you tried to calculate or simulate it?

Comment: when charged, the controlling circuit regulates the voltage some mV (e.g. 100mV) higher than the voltage of the Battery, so current flows into the battery. voltages for operation are generated from the same rail, so the charger will also power the device. peak currents still might be delivered from the battery if the charger has a current limiter (in that case the voltage will drop and the current is supplied by the battery)

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, the charger will provide the sum of the power for the laptop and the battery. If exceeded, the battery provides the excess. This means that the charger may operates at its maximum capacity and will get warm. This is not an issue if you use the charger recommended for that laptop.

Answer (score 1):

While it is often called a "charger", the device that plugs in to the laptop is simply a power supply.

All the time the laptop is plugged in, it's powered by the power supply.

If the battery needs charging, the laptop charges it. If not, the battery does nothing.